# Register Jar from the lib-Folder as an Application in Spring Data Flow

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a self-contained application with Spring Data Flow (Mesos). To do that i want to register sinks/processors/sources that are maven-dependencies of my project.

I know that spring-data-flow accepts classpath:// as a scheme for references but it appears to be unable to find any jar located in the resource folder or (optimaly) the lib folder.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [lib/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-ftp-1.0.0.M1.jar] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

How can i reference files from within my self-contained jar properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a self-contained application with Spring Data Flow (Mesos)

What are the reasons behind "self-contained" solution? Why not register the apps from our repository directly?

There's already a way to register the OOTB applications using the "bitly" links that we provide. Please review the stream [registration section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps) from the reference guide.

More importantly, the latest release of SCDF's Mesos-server does not support maven artifacts. You'd have to use docker images instead. The docs linked above includes the "bitly" link for [docker apps](https://hub.docker.com/u/springcloudstream/), too.

Comment: i dont have a private maven repo available on our distributed infrastructure (for custom modules), so bringing all modules i need for my streams internaly sounded like a good alternative. But thanks to your answer i have a bigger problem: if the mesos deployer only supports docker images (makes kind of sense), then how do i build those. i cant find examples for a valid dockerfile for a module. do i just have to run my packaged module applications?

Comment: We generate Docker images for all the [OOTB applications](https://hub.docker.com/u/springcloudstream/) already. Refer to SCDF's Mesos Server reference guide on how to [register and use](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-mesos/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#_getting_started) them.

Comment: i know that, but what do i do with my own modules?

Comment: There's a gap in docs - created [#184](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/issues/184) to cover it.

Comment: In the meantime, you can follow these steps: 1) Build custom app 2) Add app to [`app-dependencies`](http://bitly/2acDbWV) POM 3) Add app to the [`app-generator`](http://bitly/2ajN6vh) POM 4) Build the project by following [README](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/blob/master/README.adoc) instructions

(_p.s: you'd need to add `.`s in those bitly links_)